# Server 2012, Server Manager Dashboard

Tags: windows-server-2012, exchange-2013

New installation of Server 2012 R2 with Exchange 2016.

The dashboard is showing 'Microsoft Exchange Notifications Broker' as stopped and giving a red error in the dashboard

It is normal for the service to start and then stop if there is nothing for it to do!!
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150489(v=exchg.160).aspx

The service is set to Automatic also shows the error if set to delayed.

Is there a way to stop the dashboard from monitoring this service?

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click the Services dropdown and uncheck the services that you don't want to see/be alerted on.

[image]